# Redirect after photo upload and avoid showing graph api endpoint response - PHP SDK 3

Tags: php, file-upload, facebook-graph-api, response, endpoint

I'm trying to build an iframe app for my work through which a user can upload a photo to their photos.

I have managed to get the photos to upload - BUT once the photo is uploaded, my app just shows the new photos ID (endpoint response) and removes everything else from the iframe (as shown in the second link below).

I want to be able to redirect to a success page or even just back to my app without showing this 'endpoint response'.

I have been using this tutorial to get me to where I am:
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/

and

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

for the upload.

This is the first time I have attempted to build a Facebook app and I am really struggling, any help would really be appreciated.

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how you can redirect a page a condition is true (i.e. the picture has been uploaded), header("Location: url") might be the answer. When using header location there are two concerns:

1) Make sure that the url you are redirecting to is absolute (including http://lalalala/llala/la)

and

2) Nothing can be outputted before your header. Consider this example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.

I don't think I can use headers, it seems like when the photo is sent to the graph api it gives a response which is - I think - JSON and this takes over my apps iFrame, so none of the code I put in my app is in the iFrame anymore.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure I that I understand exactly what you mean.